# getting mongodb data from express server using fetch on reactjs frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, promise, fetch

Creating a notes app on MERN stack https://lutif.github.io/Notes-Keeper/ ,
I have a mongodb , I want to fetch notes on database and then render those on frontend. However reactjs doesn't allow me to initialize state (call useState) in a call back. how do it get my fetch data and use it in useState. any pointer will be helpful.

> 

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

import addNotedb from '../APICalls/addNote';
import getNotesListdb from '../APICalls/getNotesList';


function App() {
getNotesListdb().then(nojson=>nojson.json()).then( notesListdb=>
  {const [notes, setNotes] = useState([...notesListdb]);}
)
  function addNote(newNote) {
    // const noteId = 
    addNotedb(newNote);
    console.log('calling add note with ', newNote);
    // newNote.Id = newNote;
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
    
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
const endpoint = '/api/notes';
export default function getNotes() {
    
    let promise =
        fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }
    )
    
    return promise
}
```

Comment: Minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tu-7bkr9

Comment: thanks that worked. I understand need to update state before render instead of initialise it.

Comment: The main takeaway is that you can't declare the `const` array inside the callback, mostly because you couldn't use it anywhere else in your component. The component is in fact rendered twice, first at the very start, when the array is still empty, then a second time after the state is updated with the fetched result.